# Nginx serves wrong domain site. It doesn't show default site if no configuration applies

Tags: nginx

I have 3 domains that are pointing to my server and the server runs confluence and jira application from atlissan.

For whatever reason, my nginx is acting strange.

I have the default nginx configuration not touched. If I visit `test.domain.com`, nginx shows me the default nginx page.

I have a configuration for jira that is enabled in the sites-enabled:

```
server {
   listen jira.domain.com:443 ssl;
   server_name jira.domain.com;
   server_tokens off;
   location / {
       proxy_set_header Host $server_name;
       proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
       proxy_set_header X-Forewarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
       proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
       proxy_set_header Authorization "";
       proxy_pass       http://127.0.0.1:8080; #Jira port
   }

   # certbot ssl settings
   #htaccess settings
}

server {
    if ($host = jira.domain.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }
    listen jira.domain.com:80;
    server_name jira.domain.com;
    return 404;
}
```

Now, If I visit `jira.domain.com`, I am getting jira served.

Those are my only two configurations. The point is that I am getting Jira served even if I visit from `confluence.domain.com`. If I change the port in the proxy pass to the confluence port, I am getting confluence served. Why is Nginx picking up if I come from confluence.domain.com? Even Jira tells me that I am coming from confluence.domain.com.

All domain entries are A records to the IP of the server.

Comment: change to `listen 443 ssl;` & `listen 80;`. You also do not need an `if $host` because you already have named server under the `server_name` directive. It only 'listens' for that name anyway. Just return 301 and be done.

Comment: Something like https://pastebin.com/iqw62bPt should work..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se here what we have in default config you have a line `listen 80 default_server;`
`default_server` means that this config will be used for every domain for which you don't have config in nginx. Probably `test.domain.com` you was visiting via `http` and you nginx routed you using default config to nginx start page.

Meanwhile you visited confluence via `https`, and for now you have only one config in nginx that can respond on `443` port - that one what you have for jira (in nginx default config `https` section is commented out) so it routes you via jira config to `proxy_pass       http://127.0.0.1:8080;` Even if you will go now for `https://test.domain.com` nginx will show you jira.

So, basically, to make jira and confluence work with `https` domain on one server, you will need to create two different configs - one for `jira.domain.com` and second one for `confluence.domain.com` with `proxy_pass` on different ports.

Comment: nope. just default and this are syslined

Comment: sure. direcly the first line. it works if I visit with `test.domain.com`. I am getting the default nginx screen. However, not from `confluence.domain.test`

Comment: You trying to visit `confluence.domain.test` via https?

Comment: yes. I have created the ssl certificate via certbot

Comment: I dont know why, but I've restarted the server a second time and now it works! Thanks for your Time!

Comment: @PatrickSchocke btw, when you doing any changes in nginx config - you need to do restart or reload of nginx, cause only when you doing this nginx re-reads config files.

Comment: I've restarted nginx every time. I dont knwo why, but restarting the server worked for me...

Comment: @PatrickSchocke Perhaps your text editor does not save fast enough for nginx to notice the changes. I have this issue sometimes, because I have vim create a backup file before saving.

Answer (score 2):

nginx documentation doesn't tell that it supports domain names in `listen` directives. You should only use port number there, unless you have a specific need to bind nginx only to a specific interface.